# Java Eclipse cant add external jars

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm watching a YouTube tutorial and the instructor adds external Jar files into the JRE System Library, but the button "Add External JARs" is not clickable for me. How can I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have selected the `JRE System Library` in the panel. Un-select that and you will be able to add external jars.

You can click on the `Classpath` or `Modulepath` to move the control away.

Please download the `jars` from [here](https://download.jar-download.com/cache_jars/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/4.0.0-alpha-3/jar_files.zip).

Extract the zip and from the extracted folder select all the necessary jar you need.

For the classes mentioned in the comment. Please add below jars:

```
1. selenium-api-4.0.0-alpha-3.jar
2. selenium-chrome-driver-4.0.0-alpha-3.jar
```

NOTE: The versions might vary.

Comment: If you look at this video, it appears as if she's adding it into the JRE System Library - https://youtu.be/U-JRw7yRFcA?t=401  Can I not do that?

Comment: Not sure, what she is doing, but, you can't add jars to existing jars. You please try what the answer suggests, it will work. Let me know if you face any issues there.

Comment: I imported the JAR file but it still doesn't recognize the imports :(

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

Answer (score 1):

All of them at first are unclickable when you try to click on them , but rather you right click on the *modulepath* under the libraries (Build path) , then they will become clickable and then import what you want. That's how its simple.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you included a screenshot demonstrating what you're talking about.